# adding additional conditions to ternary statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following statement.

```
(state) => checkSelectedAccountExists(state) ? 

state.atlasSales.deepDive.selectedAccount.propertyManagementSoftware : {}
```

**Pseudo-Code:**

---

- `(state) => checkSelectedAccountExists(state) ?

  state.atlasSales.deepDive.selectedAccount.propertyManagementSoftware : {}`

What happens now is, I either get

- Property Management Software: N/A
  or
- Property Management Software: Buildium

**How do I make so that if Property Management Software: returns N/A, then it shouldn't up at all?** Basically i only want Property Management Software to show if it acctually is a software name.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow skphi13! It's not clear what you are asking, so it will be hard for us to help you. Could you include the code you have written so far?

Comment: What does `checkSelectedAccountExists(state)` check for and what does it return? Is `state.atlasSales.deepDive.selectedAccount.propertyManagementSoftware` have a valid value as `N/A`?

Comment: `checkSelectedAccountExists(state)` checks if the account exist. if the account exist it pass the account information which shows the _Property Management Software_. Yes `state.atlasSales.deepDive.selectedAccount.propertyManagementSoftware` does have a valid value N/A

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't exactly clear, but I think you're looking for *nested* ternary conditions.

```
(state) => !checkSelectedAccountExists(state) ? 
    {} :
    state.atlasSales.deepDive.selectedAccount.propertyManagementSoftware === 'N/A' ?
        false :
        true;
```

I'm not sure what your return values *should* be (are you trying to render a component??), but this is how it can be read:

```
if (!checkSelectedAccountExists(state)) {
    return {};
} else {
    if (state.atlasSales.deepDive.selectedAccount.propertyManagementSoftware === 'N/A') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hopefully, that's clear enough for you to adapt to your goal.